# Excel filter for top n values AFTER another filter has been applied

Tags: excel, vba

I've been googling trying to understand why excel behaves in this way but can't seem to find a straightforward explanation for it:
Why can't I filter for top n items AFTER another filter has been applied? I'm trying to do this with VBA using the below formula but it only filters for a single value. Filter manually also produces the same result:

```
.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & Date - 3
.AutoFilter Field:=35, Criteria1:="10", Operator:=xlTop10Items
```

Why does excel behave in this way and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular filter examines the entire table, not just the filtered rows. I'm guessing that to add that functionality, there would have to be information as to the order that the filters for different columns was applied. Or maybe it is by design in applying each column filter as an `AND` type of operation.

There are several options:

1. Use the Advanced Filter with a Formula Criteria for the values
2. Use Power Query in which a subsequent filter will rely on the previous operations.

I set up a simple table with two columns `Date` and `Value`.  The Headers are in `A7:B7`

[image]

There are two columns of criteria

[image]

```
Formula:  =B8>=AGGREGATE(14,4,(Table1[Date]>=(TODAY()-3))*Table1[Value],10)
Date:  =">="&TODAY()-3
```

Upon executing the Advanced Filter:

[image]

Here is an example of VBA code for the above 2 column table.  You'll need to adapt it to your real data. Note that in the VBA code, I did not use the Table references, but you can certainly alter that if you prefer.

```
Option Explicit
Sub specialFilter()
    Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet
    Dim dataRng As Range, critRng As Range
    Dim datesRng As Range, valuesRng As Range
    
'Set ranges
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    Set dataRng = .Range(.Cells(7, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    Set datesRng = .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set valuesRng = .Range(.Cells(8, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    Set critRng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 2))
End With

'enter criteria
With critRng
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Formula"
    .Cells(2, 1).Formula = "=B8>=AGGREGATE(14,4,(" & datesRng.Address & ">=(TODAY()-3))*" & valuesRng.Address & ",10)"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = dataRng.Cells(1, 1) 'must be same as column header
    .Cells(2, 2).Formula = "="">="" & TODAY()-3"
End With

If WS.FilterMode = True Then WS.ShowAllData
dataRng.AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterInPlace, _
    criteriarange:=critRng, _
    Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Another option is **Power Query** *(available in Excel 2010 and later)*
Unfortunately, the criteria cannot be set up from the GUI, but requires using the Advanced Editor.

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Date] >= Date.AddDays( DateTime.Date(DateTime.FixedLocalNow()),-3)),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each [Value] >= List.Min(List.MaxN(#"Filtered Rows"[Value],10)))
in
    #"Filtered Rows1"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A2:A6") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B2:B6") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:B6")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

End Sub

Hopefully you know how to change the page reference. You can also identify the last row using something like...

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

the instead of Range(.....
use Cell(lastrow,[column#]).....

that should get you where you want to go.

Comment: This does not answer the question, sorting and filtering are two different operations.

Comment: I'm trying to filter, not sort